# How do I use cURL to update Twitter?

Tags: bash, curl, twitter

I'm looking to update twitter using cURL.  I've written a bash function, but I'm not sure how to get it to accept a line as an argument to use as status text.  The current function just accepts the first word as an argument.  Also, can I prevent it from returning the XML file or suppress it from going to stdout?

```
#!/bin/bash
function tweet {
  curl -s -u username:password -d status="$1" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
}
```

PS - I know there are other questions re: cURL and Twitter on SO but none answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and yes. In bash, you want to use $* instead of $1. To suppress anything from going to stdout, just redirect it to /dev/null. So, your code would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
function tweet {
  curl -u username:password -d status="$*" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml > /dev/null
}
```

**UPDATE**

As already pointed out, this will no longer work because of the changes to twitter's authentication method. I'll leave it here for historical reasons.

Comment: @Joe Actually, using the -s switch with cURL makes it silent and so it also hides the progress meter

Comment: You can do `curl -o /dev/null -s ...` also.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CURRENTLY WORKING bash script which will post to Twitter:

[http://web.archive.org/web/20140625220735/http://360percents.com/posts/command-line-twitter-status-update-for-linux-and-mac/](http://360percents.com/posts/command-line-twitter-status-update-for-linux-and-mac/)

Written in bash using curl. Works perfectly on Ubuntu!

Comment: Sorry, the link is http://360percents.com/posts/command-line-twitter-status-update-for-linux-and-mac/

Comment: I changed the dead link to use a waybackmachine snapshot. Also copied the script from that page to https://gist.github.com/Synesso/7201691667f3d74d87c8e9eb74af3013

Answer (score 1):

Random guess:  When typing the command in bash, have you tried putting the first command line arg in "" so it groups the whole post into $1?  That works in some shells.

Comment: That worked for the argument alright, thanks, would prefer not to need to though.  Any idea how to suppress the returned output?  Maybe I need to write a more detailed function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to create a variable and publish it on twitter.
I published my current ip via the following code:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3909/tweet-my-ip-see-your-machine-ip-on-twitter-

Answer (score 0):

to tweet using twitter you will need a **post_authenticity_token** along with your ***username*** and ***password***.
this token can be obtained from your profile page by fetching it using curl (after you login with curl). i experimented with curl and was able to tweet using curl. you can find my code at
http://pastebin.com/a5eBcEeP .